# Component gets re-initialized on props update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

I have a component inside `formik` -based step wizard.

I make use of `useField`, `useEffect` and `useState` hooks as below:

```
const [counts, countsMeta, countsHelpers] = useField('counts');
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  countsHelpers.setValue(
    Array(event.book && event.book.length ? event.book.length : 0).fill(0)
  );
  // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [event.book]);
```

I understand that my `useEffect` should only be called once, no matter what as long as `event.book` never changes.

I also have a way to apply coupons as below:

```
        <div className={styles.coupon}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faPlusSquare}
            onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}
          />{' '}
          coupon code
          {visible && (
            <div>
              <input
                id='coupon'
                type='text'
                value={values.coupon || ''}
                onChange={onChange}
                placeholder='Coupon code'
                className={errors.coupon ? styles.error : ''}
              />
              <div
                className={styles.apply}
                onClick={() => loadPromo(values.coupon)}
              >
                Apply
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
```

For some reason I cannot pinpoint, when I call `loadPromo()` my component re-initializes. Once it happens, state and fields are reset e.g. `visible` is again set to `false` and `counts` array reinitialized with zeros. After that, everything is working fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would say that it would be valuable to display  `loadPromo` method to provide you better assistance

Comment: That method loads promo into redux, which I load into the component via reselect. Basically, it is a fetch, although I do set headers in addition to calling fetch API. I don't think that this is relevant.

Comment: the exposed code by itself looks fine. it could eventually happen if your component exists within some condition like `{isValid && <Component />`, and `isValid` changes. you could add an `useEffect` with only `console.log('mounted')` with `[]` as second param to check if you component is being unmounted and mounted again. if it doesn't print `mounted` again means there is an update state causing this as a side effect on loadPromo somewehere, now if it does print than your component is being unmounted and mounted again during the process.

Comment: Yes, component re-initializes so Effect hook gets called. I am just unsure why.